# Employee hiring function does not hire employee despite a vacant post

Tags: python, enums

I have a class model based on an `Employee` and  `Company` class. In the following, a company can `apply_in_company` for the desired `role` and `team`. The `Company` has a function `hire_employee` that accepts the employee only if the post is not occupied, and the other requirements are met. `Role` and `Team` are two `Enum`s with some roles and teams.

In `hire_employee`, the code checks to see if `team` and `role` of the applicant both match with a team and role of an `employee` in the company. If they do, the post is occupied and the applicant is rejected. The problem faced here, when applying with two different employees is that despite having different `team` the second `employee` is rejected.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from enum import Enum, auto


class CompanyRoles(Enum):
    MANAGER = auto
    LEAD = auto
    WORKER = auto
    INTERN = auto


class CompanyTeams(Enum):
    MARKETING = auto
    PRODUCT = auto
    DESIGN = auto
    SALES = auto
    FINANCE = auto


@dataclass
class Company():

    name : str
    minimum_hiring_grades : int
    required_work_experience_years : int
    employee_leaves : int
    employee_bonus_percent : int
    employee_working_days : int
    employee_base : list = field(init = False, default_factory = list)
    employees : list = field(init = False, default_factory = list)

    def hire_employee(self, applicant, role, team) -> bool:
        employee_ineligibile = applicant.grades_percent_average < self.minimum_hiring_grades and applicant.work_experience_years < self.required_work_experience_years 
        for employee in self.employee_base:  #check if role occupied in applied team
            if employee.role == role and employee.team == team:
                print("This position was occupied, apply for another position.")
                return False
        if employee_ineligibile:  #check if employee grades and work experience is sufficient
            print("You did not meet our requirements.")
            return False 
        print("You are hired!")
        self.employee_base.append(applicant)
        self.employees = [employee.name for employee in self.employee_base]  
        return True



@dataclass
class Employee:
    name : str
    grades_percent_average : int
    work_experience_years : int
    role : Enum = field(init = False, default = None)
    team : Enum = field(init = False, default = None)
    company : object = field(init = False, default= None)
    working_days : int = field(init = False, default= 0)
    bonus_percent : int = field(init = False, default= 0)
    has_job : bool = field(init = False, default= False)
    id : object = field(init = False, default= None)


    def apply_in_company(self, company, role, team) -> None:
        accepted = company.hire_employee(self, role, team)
        if accepted:
            self.company = company
            self.has_job = True
            self.working_days = company.employee_working_days
            self.bonus_percent = company.employee_bonus_percent
            self.available_leaves = company.employee_leaves
            self.salary_dollars = self.grades_percent_average + self.work_experience_years * 1000
            self.role = role
            self.team = team
            self.id = self
```

Here is the code where the whole program is run.

```py
google = Company("Google Inc.", 90, 5, 30, 25, 300)
sam = Employee("Sam", 90, 5)
richard = Employee("Richard", 91, 7)
sam.apply_in_company(google, CompanyRoles.LEAD, CompanyTeams.DESIGN)
richard.apply_in_company(google, CompanyRoles.LEAD, CompanyTeams.FINANCE)
```

Here, the following output is given.

```
 Arham was hired!
This position was occupied, apply for another position.
```

Despite having a different `team`, `richard` is declined.
Also, when printing `team`, I recieve :

```
CompanyTeams.MARKETING
```

despite the team inputed being `CompanyTeams.FINANCE`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `auto` is a function, and should be called to create a different instance for each assignment.  As you have it now, only the first name in each enum is unique, and all the others are aliases.

Your class should look like:

```
class CompanyRoles(Enum):
    MANAGER = auto()
    LEAD = auto()
    ...
```

In other words, add `()` to each `auto` in your enums.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't really realise ```auto``` was a function, thanks for telling me